# Configure cron job to run every 15 minutes on Jenkins

Tags: unix, jenkins, cron

How can I run a cron job every 15 mins on Jenkins?

This is what I've tried :

On Jenkins I have a job set to run every 15 mins using this cron syntax  :

```
14 * * * *
```

But the job executes every hour instead of 15 mins.

I'm receiving a warning about the format of the cron syntax :

```
Spread load evenly by using ‘H * * * *’ rather than ‘14 * * * *’
```

Could this be the reason why the cron job executes every hour instead of 15 mins ?

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Your syntax is slightly wrong.  Say:

```
*/15 * * * * command
  |
  |--> `*/15` would imply every 15 minutes.
```

`*` indicates that the cron expression matches for all values of the field.

`/` describes increments of ranges.

Comment: does this run every 15 minutes from the time the crontab was saved or every 15 minutes like 1:00, 1:15, 1:30, 1:45?

Comment: Every fifteen minutes starting on the hour: 00, 15, 30, 45, etc.

Answer (score 79):

**1)** Your cron is wrong. If you want to run job every 15 mins on Jenkins use this:

```
H/15 * * * *
```

**2)** Warning from Jenkins `Spread load evenly by using ‘...’ rather than ‘...’` came with [JENKINS-17311](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17311):

> To allow periodically scheduled tasks to produce even load on the system, the symbol H (for “hash”) should be used wherever possible. For example, using 0 0 * * * for a dozen daily jobs will cause a large spike at midnight. In contrast, using H H * * * would still execute each job once a day, but not all at the same time, better using limited resources.

Examples:

- `H/15 * * * *` - every fifteen minutes (perhaps at :07, :22, :37, :52):
- `H(0-29)/10 * * * *` - every ten minutes in the first half of every hour (three times, perhaps at :04, :14, :24)
- `H 9-16/2 * * 1-5` - once every two hours every weekday (perhaps at 10:38 AM, 12:38 PM, 2:38 PM, 4:38 PM)
- `H H 1,15 1-11 *` - once a day on the 1st and 15th of every month except December

Comment: Using "H/15 * * * *" will trigger the following inline error: `Invalid input: "H/15 * * * *": line 1:2: unexpected token: /`

Comment: Not sure if the above comment is relevant as the `H` is specific to [jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47302607/meaning-of-h-5-in-cron-jenkins)

Comment: I'm getting "unexpected token: /" as well when using forward slash in any cron increment/range specification like the OP needs. I have tried single/double quotes, escaping slash with backslash. What's the solution?

Comment: For those who may wonder: we have more than a dozen jenkins controllers, each with the same job in the same folder.  "H * * * *" makes them all run every day at the SAME TIME.

Answer (score 10):

It should be,

```
*/15 * * * *  your_command_or_whatever
```

Comment: This is accurate for Cron, but not for Jenkins CRON. You cannot specify a command