# How can I make my web application always online even no one open my site

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have create an Online Application.In every 15 minutes interval it automatically generates results and save to database. It works fine when the website is open; But it does not work at all when the website is closed. How can I always make my website online even no one open it???.Please give me Solution. Thank You

Comment: Without knowing much about the architecture, that kind of thing is typically handled by a server service or database job.

Comment: What do you mean always online? If your webserver's uptime is good it is always online? Please clarify your question. We need more details otherwise your question will turn a downvote fest and nobody give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are going to want to set up a [cron job](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/scheduling-tasks-with-cron-jobs--net-8800) that runs every 15 minutes (see link for tutorial).

Answer (score 0):

I want to introduce you to **CRON**

**What is cron?**

*Cron is the name of program that enables unix users to execute commands or
scripts (groups of commands) automatically at a specified time/date. It is
normally used for sys admin commands, like makewhatis, which builds a
search database for the man -k command, or for running a backup script, 
but can be used for anything. A common use for it today is connecting to 
the internet and downloading your email.*

```
# * * * * *  command to execute
 # │ │ │ │ │
 # │ │ │ │ │
 # │ │ │ │ └───── day of week (0 - 6) (0 to 6 are Sunday to Saturday, or use names; 7 is Sunday, the same as 0)
 # │ │ │ └────────── month (1 - 12)
 # │ │ └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
 # │ └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
 # └───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

Here is how you set it up to run every 15 minute

```
*/15 * * * * your_command_or_whatever
  |
  |--> `*/15` would imply every 15 minutes.
```

there are many great resources on cron

[Configure cron job to run every 15 minutes on Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19443732/1380867)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#

https://www.drupal.org/node/11336