# PHP script not running from cron

Tags: php, cron

I have the following command:

```
php /var/www/html/XYZ/api_new/XYZ-API/src/public/fetch_events/fetch_events.php
```

This runs perfectly from the command line. However, I want it to run as a cron job every 15 mins, so I added the following entry to my crontab:

```
15 * * * * php /var/www/html/XYZ/api_new/XYZ-API/src/public/fetch_events/fetch_events.php
```

This however, does not seem to work at all. It does not even show up in my system logs (all my other cron jobs do show up).

Any ideas?

Comment: see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443732/configure-cron-job-to-run-every-15-minutes-on-jenkins. your script is making it run every 15th minute of an hour, not every 15 minutes.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it is not a syntax problem. It does not work with all 5 asterisks either.

Comment: try reading this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working for i do not exactly know what's happening on your cron job.

Answer (score 0):

There's not really enough information to answer your question, but here are some things that might help.

Sometimes cronjobs don't have context for where to find these programs, so do `which php` and replace the full path with the php command.

/var/log/cron *should* have a record of it running, but if there's a problem, you might not know why.  Try appending the following to the end of the cron line to aid in debuging:

`>> /tmp/fetch_events.log 2>&1`

This file will probably contain some hints as to what's going on when the cron *does* fire.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it