# Web hosting does not support cron jobs. How can I run my scraping script remotely to mine data and then send it to my hosting's mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, curl, cron, mining

I am currently using Yahoo web hosting. I found out that Yahoo does not support cron jobs. What I want to do is run my script and feed the data it mines into Yahoo's mysql database. The script is written in PHP, takes a couple hours to complete, and I would like it to be running constantly to keep my information updated. Is it possible to run the script in my local environment and somehow send that information to the Yahoo's mysql server? Is there a free online service which would run my script for me and send the data?

Comment: A PHP script which runs a couple of hours? No way ...

Comment: there are, just google "online cron service". Those do only request a web URL though, so you have to get your script working that way. They won'T wait for an answer, neither will they do anything if they receive one.

Comment: @Chris Not true, there are a couple of (free) services that you can use to call a script on your server (as long as it's publicly accessible of course)

Comment: [StackOverflow: cron Alternative](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/163476/free-alternative-to-webcron)

Comment: I checked out cronme which seems promising although would I be able to send the data I get to my remote mysql server hosted by Yahoo? If I run the script via Yahoo web hosting it times out since it takes too long.

Comment: YOu won't most likely find ANY host that allows you to run scripts that run an hour. I wouldn't even do such tihngs on my own server... YOu need to have webspace that allows you to run the scruipt, then you can use cron services to request it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jenkins for this. A cron job configuration could be done in the way it is specified [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472645/how-to-schedule-jobs-in-jenkins). Complete step by step guide could be also find [here](https://developer.cloudbees.com/bin/view/DEV/Getting+started%20with%20Jenkins).