# How to schedule Jenkins job every Hour for the next 12 hours

Tags: jenkins

I would like to schedule Jenkins job for example every hour between 9 am to 9 pm.

```
* 1/12 * * *
```

is not working.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to schedule jobs in Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472645/how-to-schedule-jobs-in-jenkins)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jenkins uses Cron expressions for scheduling. You can see details in answer to linked question in the comments.

Answer to your question would be `H 9-21 * * *`

Answer (score 0):

TO make it run every 12 hours once,
H */12 * * *

Comment: OP asked for the syntax for every hour for 12 hours, not every 12 hours. Probably 0 9-18 * * *