# Schedule a Jenkins Job to run hourly everyday but skip midnight (00:00) and resume again from 01:00 till 23:00

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-builder

I have a Jenkins job which I would like to run from (01:00) 1 AM till (23:00) 11PM but skip midnight (00:00) and resume again from (01:00) on a daily basis. The thread [How to schedule Jenkins job every Hour for the next 12 hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837243/how-to-schedule-jenkins-job-every-hour-for-the-next-12-hours?rq=1#) had this example H 9-21 * * * which i have changed to H 1-23 * * * to cater for my example.

Am I on the right track perhaps with using H 1-23 * * * ??

Comment: yes, your cron expression is right.

Comment: Worked indeed thank you! ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that should work.  There is a cron tester you can look that will show you the cron version of that, and for Jenkins you just replace the 0 with the H.

[`http://cron.schlitt.info/index.php?cron=0+1-23+*+*+*+&iterations=50&test=Test`](http://cron.schlitt.info/index.php?cron=0%201-23%20*%20*%20*%20&iterations=50&test=Test)

Comment: Thanks for this @hobo loafers, it worked perfectly fine.