# I would like to run job in Jenkins tool on every Wednesday morning at 7AM BST

Tags: jenkins

I would like to run job in Jenkins tool on every Wednesday morning at 7AM BST..
what's correct expression needs to use in Build Triggers?

Comment: Please have a look -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472645/how-do-i-schedule-jobs-in-jenkins

Comment: Thanks for your help.. .. Express mentioned as "0 6 * * 3"


---------------------------
Spread load evenly by using ‘H 6 * * 3’ rather than ‘0 6 * * 3’
Would last have run at Wednesday, November 14, 2018 6:00:00 AM CET; would next run at Wednesday, November 21, 2018 6:00:00 AM CET.
-------------------------

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help.. ..

Express mentioned as "0 6 * * 3"

---

Spread load evenly by using ‘H 6 * * 3’ rather than ‘0 6 * * 3’ Would last have run at Wednesday, November 14, 2018 6:00:00 AM CET; would next run at Wednesday, November 21, 2018 6:00:00 AM CET. ------------------------- – Girish B Nov 16 at 16:07