# Jenkins Build Pipeline Scheduled Trigger ( 1 time per week )

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins configure, I setting Build periodically same as:
[image: Setting Build periodically]
I want to Jenkins will automatically activate every Thursday at 1am.
But Jenkins does not trigger at that time.

Thank!

Comment: You teally only want either say of the week (last col), and leaveday of the month (3rd col) alone. One of [many explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12472740/598141).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I schedule jobs in Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472645/how-do-i-schedule-jobs-in-jenkins)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use in below way:

```
H 1 * * 4
```

[image]