# Automation, scheduled tests

Tags: python, selenium, automation, scheduled-tasks, ui-automation

Is it possible to run and test scheduled tests right away rather than waiting for a set time if I can't change the scheduled test time?
For example, suppose I have a weekly scheduled test that runs once a week on a specified day, and I need to run it right now and compare the results to the downloaded file and assert

Comment: How have you scheduled your test cases ?

Comment: No. I'm not using unit testing I'm running my test with pytest

Comment: How did you achieve this `For example, suppose I have a weekly scheduled test that runs once a week on a specified day` ?

Comment: I didn't active it, I am looking for a way to activate it immediately rather than waiting a week.
I am not familiar with unit testing, how can I use it to trigger my test and run the weekly test right now instead if waiting?

Answer (score 0):

A free tool to scheduled your test in Jenkins. (My recommendation)

> The leading open source automation server, Jenkins provides hundreds
> of plugins to support building, deploying and automating any project.

more..

> Jenkins is a self-contained, open source automation server which can
> be used to automate all sorts of tasks related to building, testing,
> and delivering or deploying software.
>
> Jenkins can be installed through native system packages, Docker, or
> even run standalone by any machine with a Java Runtime Environment
> (JRE) installed

You can have a scheduler, that could get trigger whenever you want to.

to learn more you can check [this link about scheduling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472645/how-do-i-schedule-jobs-in-jenkins)

This is [Jenkins official docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/)