# How to run a JMeter soak test for more than a day?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I want to run a soak test using JMeter for say 3 days. The test should begin on the first day when the command is triggered, should run up to 10pm, pause overnight, resume at 8am the next day and run till 10pm. Repeat the pause and resume cycle for the third day and then end. How can this be achieved?

I tried the method provided [here](https://octoperf.com/blog/2019/02/21/soak-test-practical-example/#jmeter-test-plan). But it records the test data only for the duration mentioned in the thread group (ramp-up, hold, ramp down if any) and then stays in idle state until terminating through command prompt.

Comment: A test like this is designed to test for resource/memory leaks.  Have you considered cutting your architecture down to simply one non-load balanced node of each type, then run a load slightly hotter than that one node is expected to handle.    Simply watch your resources over the course of the test and a leak should manifest itself fairly quickly (4 hours or less)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just scheduling the test execution via your operating system toolchain like [Windows Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) or [Linux cron](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/linux-cron-command) or [MacOS launchd](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/ScheduledJobs.html) or going for a continuous integration solution like [Jenkins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-jenkins-integration) and use its [jobs scheduling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12472645/how-do-i-schedule-jobs-in-jenkins)

If you use the same .jtl file and won't provide `-f` parameter the new results will be appended to the existing file.

With regards to the "method provided here" you should either ask "there" or provide your test plan and [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)