# Schedule at Jenkins job at 3pm everyday

Tags: jenkins, scheduled-tasks, jenkins-job-dsl

I am trying to set up a Jenkins job to run everyday at 5am and the syntax I use it * 5 * * *. I am unsure if this syntax is correct, could anyone advise? I saw an example on stackoverflow for 9:30am but I am unsure if this runs in military time or not.

If there are any websites that I can look at, would be great as well!

Comment: There are dozens of tools to help you with this, see e.g. https://crontab.guru/

Comment: Thank you! Still new to learning Jenkins which is why I wasnt aware of the tools. This will make my job easier @jonrsharpe

Comment: Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12472740/22270964). I think this is exactly what you need.

Comment: @MaksimEliseev that post is exactly what I needed to give me a better understanding of the syntax, thank you!